# Обработка запроса GET сайтом

Tags: php, linux

Есть форма на другом сайте:

```
<form action=exp.php method=GET id=go_show target="exp_frm"  >
```

какие-то строчечки-рюшечки

```
</form>
```

Как с моего сайта отправить запрос на страницу с этой формой? в ответ приходит предложение сохранить файл.

Comment: curl() использовать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> мой сервер должен только получить готовую ссылку от другого сервера для скачивания

Значит, поставьте сабмит, по нажатию на который будет происходить отправка формы и, соответственно, получение файла со стороннего сервера. Потому что не факт, что автор скрипта захочет делиться прямой ссылкой на файл.

Comment: прямой ссылки не будет, там страница сама генерирует новый файл и дает мне готовую ссылку на этот файл

Answer (score 1):

Используйте **Curl**, вот интересная статья: [curl](http://www.kabit.ru/all/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%81-curl)

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, все из-за неправильной настройки Apach...

Comment: пардон. при чем тут настройки к поиску технологии как это выполнить?

Comment: Пардон... Во время выполнения данного скрипта вас перенаправляет на страницу exp.php и потом уже предлагается сохранить?

Comment: меня это не должно перенаправлять. мой сервер должен только получить готовую ссылку от другого сервера для скачивания. я могу скачивать а могу и не скачивать